# Is there a way to consciously freeze an Android phone for some time from within an application?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an application that will, upon user's consent, freeze the phone for some time during which period the user can't really close the application or move out to another. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not unless the phone is rooted, the home button functionality by example can't be changed

Comment: Well I have not tested that, but what bumped into my head is that you can create a sticky service. Create a layout with width and length set to window's size and make it be visible on top of the content of the screen so that any touch intercept will go to that layout instead of the overlaid content. And after that period of time, end that service. However status bar and navigation bar would still be functional during the freeze time as the layout would not overlay the window insets.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "freeze" the phone, but there is a way to block usage:
you can create a full screen overlay.

[Here is a random sample](https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256) from the internet.

This requires a [special permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW), and may be seen as a malware behavior so your app may not be allow in the Google Play Store.

And you have to be very careful with this, since if you do not remove it in time the user will be forced to reboot the phone.

Comment: This will only work below Oreo - since then You can always pull out notification bar and kill overlays from there.